# How to update data into database for my phoenix app in production?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to some data to my phoenix app, in multiple environment. I use distillery to release my app. I have the following idea to update the data:

1. Write a method to update data in `RelaseTasks` and create a shell script at `rel/commands`.

   This is the recommend way to run tasks by distillery, but it seems for a long life tasks. If one-time task goes here, the `ReleaseTasks` file will become bigger and bigger.
2. Write a method to update data in any file and run it via remote console.
3. Update the database manually.

Does anyone have a good idea?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think to do this you need to add migration file to update data.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it locally in production and connect to the production DB to run data processing utilities. You can also write data processing functions in a utility module and execute them from the iex console on a production node. I usually write a data migration function, test it locally and then run it from a console on a production node.